# How to add oAuth to authenticate developers, not get users permission

Tags: node.js, api, oauth

I am currently creating an API (who isn't) however when I look for a way to use oAuth in the ways Facebook and twitter do to authenticate users trying to get data all i find is a way to get users permissions which I do not need, the idea of my implementation of oAuth is to authenticate the developer so when they make an API call the server knows who they are and what to serve them. I haven't tried any oAuth code because I haven't found node module that will help so far, however I can give background. I am using:

1. Mongoose, to query MongoDB
2. Express, for the HTTP Server

I do not explicitly want to use oAuth, I simply thought it was a good idea, I am open to any other way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read the OAuth [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and to decide if one of the grant flows suits for your requirements. When user(developer) logs in you grant Access Token to him/her. Now on when user makes request to API the Access Token must be on HTTP request header, extracting that Access Token on back-end service from the request you can identify the user.

It is up to you what kind of information you store to DB from the user when she/he registers to your service. But all that information can be mapped with the Access Token that user gets after succesful login or stored inside the Access Token also.